# Unity 3D jump and movement conflict

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, touch, conflict

I wanted to make an endless runner game where the player can jump and he moves forward automatically, so, for the forward movement i wanted to use the rigidbody velocity function in order to make the movement smoother and for the jump i made a custom function. My problem is, when i use in my update method the velocity function alone, it works, when i use it with my jump function it stops working. What can i do?. I tried changing the material of the floor and of the player's box collider to a really slippery one but nothing

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePrima : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _moveSpeed = 0f;              
    [SerializeField]
    private float _gravity = 9.81f;             
    [SerializeField]
    private float _jumpspeed = 3.5f;           

    public float speedAccel = 0.01f;            

    private CharacterController _controller;    

    private float _directionY;                 

    public float startSpeed;                  

    public float Yspeed = 10f;                       
        
    private int i = 0;                          

    public float touchSensibility = 50f;              

    public int accelTime = 600;
    [SerializeField]
    Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startSpeed = _moveSpeed;
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();      
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f) * _moveSpeed;
        touchControls();
    }


    public void touchControls()
    {
       


        if (SwipeManager.swipeUp && _controller.isGrounded)
        {
            _directionY = _jumpspeed;
            print("Entrato");
        }
        _directionY -= _gravity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;                      

        _controller.Move((new Vector3(0, _directionY, 0)) * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Yspeed);      



        i += 1;                                                             
        if (i % accelTime == 0)                                                   
        {
            _moveSpeed += startSpeed * speedAccel;
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit) //Checks if it collided with obstacles
    {
        if(hit.transform.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            GameOverManager.gameOver = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use the CharacterController or the Rigidbody. With the CharacterController you tell Unity where to place the character and you have to check yourself if it is a valid position. With the Rigidbody you push it in the directions you want, but the physics around the character is also interfering.

Comment: So, you mean that i should choose only one among those two solutions or either they will conflict?

Comment: Yes, you have to be very careful if you use both. Personally, I don't know any good example on when to use both - you maybe want the exact control of the CharachterController but sometimes add a bid physics, but if you don't turn of the CharacterController while the physics is playing, strange things will happen.

Comment: There are soo many good blogs about this, but after a very fast google I would recommend: https://medium.com/ironequal/unity-character-controller-vs-rigidbody-a1e243591483

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rigidbody.AddForce` to y when jumping instead of `_controller.Move`.